# Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' Jquery onclick button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

My requirement is to open the dialoge onclick Cancel button. Once 'Cancel the Reservation' is clicked, the form should be submitted.

With the below code, I am getting the error :
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

I have my div as :

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required" style="display:none">
            Are you sure about this?
</div>
```

Button as :

```
<input type="submit" id="btnCxlJob" name="btnCxlJob" value="Cancel" />
```

In document.Ready :

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            'Cancel the Reservation': function() {

                $(this).dialog('close');
                document.JobConf.submit;

            },
            'Cancel': function() {
               $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#btnCxlJob").click(function() {
        var theDialog = $("#dialog").dialog();
        alert("clicked!");
        theDialog.dialog("open");

    });
```

Although I tried suggestions from other posts for this error but could not get rid of this error.Any help is hugely appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The dialog is working as expected [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9e4dbxon/1/). Check in your page if only one version of jquery and jquery-ui-dialog is used and if they are up-to-date.

Comment: Which suggestions did you try?

Comment: I have these scripts :
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.1.9.1.min.js"></script> <link type="text/css" href="includes/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: That covers the jquery-ui version. Which jquery version are you using?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>

Comment: It is a version problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a version problem. Use jqueryui 1.9.2 with jquery 1.9.1 and you do not have the problem. It is even better if you use the most recent versions of both.

Used in my test

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool, this does solve the error. I will accept the answer. However, the dialogue window opens and it does not wait me to click the confirm button and form gets submitted. Any suggestions on this pls. Thank u very much

Comment: Is your input with the submit button Cancel inside a form?

Comment: yes , the input submit button with value cancel is inside the form

Answer (score 0):

You must prevent the submit button submitting the form. Add the event argument `e` to the function in `onClick` and use `preventDefault` on it.

```
$("#btnCxlJob").click(function(e) {
    var theDialog = $("#dialog").dialog();
    alert("clicked!");
    theDialog.dialog("open");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Replace `document.JobConf.submit;` with `$("#<id of the form>").submit();`

Use it with the id assigned to your form. If it is JobConf the code would be `$("#JobConf").submit();`.

Comment: Barry, e.preventDefault() works but the form is not getting submitted now. The form has a onsubmit function which checks the validation. If I use return false; it does not do the cancel operation but submits the form. Any more suggestions pls.

Comment: Barry, Thank you so much for helping me out. $("#JobConf").submit(); submits the form , but in the servlet the code is written to check the button name="btnCxlJob" which does the expected processing.

Comment: Here, the form is getting submitted, but the cancellation operation is not executed as it depends on passing the button name attribute. Can you please suggest a solution to this. Thank again